# Header and Footer not displaying after login

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I created a service for login that will navigate to home once login successful the problem is that whenever it navigate to home the header and footer is not showing but upon refresh they are displaying.

```
  this.auth.login().subscribe(
    res =>{
      console.log('res',res);
      let user = new User();
      user.token = res.idToken;
      this.auth.setUserVariables(user);
      localStorage.setItem("isLoggedin",true);
      this.NavCtrl.navigateForward('home');
    }
  );
```

this was supposed to bring it to the root component

> this.NavCtrl.navigateForward('home');

this is what I have on my app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  isLoggedin:boolean;
  constructor() {
      if(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedin')){
         this.isLoggedin =  true;
      }
  }
}
```

this is my app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu contentId="main-content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="tertiary">
        <ion-title>Menu Content</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">This is the menu content.</ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <div class="ion-page" id="main-content">
    <ion-header *ngIf="isLoggedin">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title align="center">Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">

      <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>

    </ion-content>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</ion-app>
```

I don't why `isLoggedin` is not reflecting instantly after login.

Answer (score 0):

you need to listen for store changes. don't do it in the constructor.

```
 @HostListener('window:storage')
  onStorageChange() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedin')){
         this.isLoggedin =  true;
      }
  }
```